# Android Studio Rendering Problems java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: android-studio

Can someone help me with thi errors.
First I had problems with design XML files, now this.
I didn't come further than just creating a project to practice for my first app....

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Preview timed out while
>   rendering the layout. This typically happens when there is an infinite
>   loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views.   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)     at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.loadBytes(FileUtilRt.java:627)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.loadBytes(FileUtil.java:1604)
>     at com.intellij.util.lang.MemoryResource.load(MemoryResource.java:74)
>     at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.getResource(JarLoader.java:134)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath$ResourceStringLoaderIterator.process(ClassPath.java:342)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath$ResourceStringLoaderIterator.process(ClassPath.java:332)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.ClasspathCache.iterateLoaders(ClasspathCache.java:98)
>     at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.getResource(ClassPath.java:106)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:220)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:119)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:73)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:62)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.shouldBeUsed(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:41)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.shouldWrap(TintContextWrapper.java:84)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.wrap(TintContextWrapper.java:45)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:150)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
>     at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.(CustomBar.java:95)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.(NavigationBar.java:52)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.(NavigationBar.java:46)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:281)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:137)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$$Lambda$169/554168569.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints on improving your question. One problem I see with your question is that you've posted a long stack trace but without formatting it so that it would be readable and without the corresponding portion of code that would provide insight into the error source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

Try to Build APK, Rebuild Project, or close and re-open your project.

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.